# How to upload image on twitter using OAuth javascript phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, twitter-oauth

I am developing an android app using PhoneGap,

In my app i am  trying to post an image onto the twitter,
   I am using OAuth authentication for the authorization and access.
   I can even tweet using this.

But i need help in how to upload an image on to twitter.
any code samples will be greatly appreciated.